# In Rails, is <resource>_path automatically available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like a basic question, but does Rails automatically interpret `<resource>_path` as a route after you have created the route (by understanding the additional `_path`)?

Comment: Do you know what happens when you write `resources :something` in routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a resourceful route will also expose a number of helpers to the controllers and views in your application. In the case of resources :photos:

```
photos_path returns /photos
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
```

Each of these helpers has a corresponding _url helper (such as photos_url) which returns the same path prefixed with the current host, port and path prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it only works on the controllers and views, not in the models.

Answer (score 0):

Resources generates named routes for use in controllers and views.

Routes can be named for easy reference. And named helpers are available for named routes. For example:

If you define a named route:

```
root to: 'blogs#index'
```

Then you can use named helpers `_url` & `_path`:

```
root_url   # => 'http://www.example.com/'
root_path  # => '/'
```

`_path` provides a site root relative path which is used most frequently. `_url` provides the full url including protocol and server name and is used for generating urls for external use (like you need a shareable link).